# Does Leiningen pass repl-options to clojure.main/repl

Tags: clojure, leiningen

The regular Clojure repl `clojure.main/repl` accepts options like `:print`, `:prompt` and `:eval` that let you hook-in and override the repl's behaviour.

E.g.

```
(clojure.main/repl 
    :print #(println "main print!" %) 
    :prompt #(println "main prompt!") 
    :eval  #(do (println "main eval!") (eval %)))
```

I assumed that Leiningen's `:repl-options` let you specify the same options, and Leiningen would pass them on to Clojure's repl. There's even a hint at this in the Leiningen repo:

> [Support :repl-options in project.clj that get passed to
>   clojure.main/repl.](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/NEWS.md#user-content-140--2010-12-02)

I cannot get this to work. It appears that Leiningen doesn't accept the same set of options as `clojure.main/repl`. `:prompt` works, although the function signature is different, and `:print` and `:eval` seem to be ignored.

Is there a way to change the print and eval behaviour in Leiningen's repl?

My `project.clj`:

```
(defproject repl-test "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]]
  :repl-options { 
    :print #(println "lein print!" %)
    :prompt (constantly "lein prompt!")
    :eval #(do (println "lein eval!") (eval %))
  }
)
```

I'm using Leiningen 2.7.1.

Background:

I've been trying to set `lein repl` to use `pprint` for its output. Again, NEWS.md hints at this:

> [Support :project-init in project.clj to allow pprint to be used in
>   :repl-options.](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/NEWS.md#user-content-161--2011-07-06)

Help with that also appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lein repl` starts nREPL, not `clojure.main/repl`. It supports a different set of options. Check sample `project.clj` for a [list of supported parameters](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L352).

Comment: Thanks, that would explain it. It looks like it used to use clojure.main/repl at some time in its past.